# Advices for implementing a timeseries table on a Mssql DB

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need advice to implement a timeseries table in MSSQL with a Spring Boot App.

Sorry guys I know MSSQL is not a timeseries DB but I have a requirement to use only MSSQL server. We have a project normally works on cloud but now we need to make it work on-premise. But the problem is as far as I read till now MSSQL is not a suitable DB for storing timeseries.

Now in my naive approach I will add a table as such:

```
@Entity(name = "timeseries")
@Table(indexes = { @Index(name = "idx_sdi_ts_time_agent_aspect", columnList = "_time, agent_id, aspect_id") })
public class TimeSeries
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "_time", nullable = false)
    private String time;

    @Column(name = "agent_id", nullable = false)
    private String agentId;

    @Column(name = "aspect_id", nullable = false)
    private String aspectId;

    @Column(name = "value", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String value;
}
```

So I have my agent-> It means the device
Also I have the name of the set of variables which is called aspect.
The raw values readed from the device will be stored in value column.

How to make this application more performant? In respect to writing data and reading it?
I know theoratically some ways to make more performant but can somebody please help me practically show repository layer codes?

```
public interface TimeseriesRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, TimeSeries>
{
    
}
```

For example which queryHints will make my queries work more fast. How can I learn the best practices in this area

Comment: I would start by using a strongly-typed datetime column rather than string. Indexes to support reading depends on your queries. If you most often query on equality of agent_id and aspect_id followed by time range, specify key columns in that order for the clustered index and create additional non-clustered indexes to support other queries (perhaps with the value column included). You might also consider columnstore indexes.

Comment: Yes.  Use columnstore for time series data in SQL Server.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: So I will change my java time variable's type to java.sql.timestamp

Comment: Yes I will also consider adding non-clustered indexes if we are going to need it in the future. I think adding unnecessary indexes will result in a bigger index data right? @DanGuzman. I dont know about columnstore indexes I will search that from the link David provided

Comment: For the SQL column type, use `dateetime2(n)`, where n is the fractional seconds you need. Additional non-clustered indexes do incur storage overhead but are often justified by improved performance for select queries. Columnstore is optimized for large scans and inherently compresses around 90% depending on your data.

Comment: @DanGuzman While I was searching for the type to use in java I came across [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-ver16) which says this: 3 Note that java.sql.Timestamp values can no longer be used to compare values from a datetime column starting from SQL Server 2016. This limitation is due to a server-side change that converts datetime to datetime2 differently, resulting in non-equitable values. The workaround to this issue is to ... use String instead of java.sql.Timestamp, or change database compatibility level to 120 or below.

Comment: @gunescelil, a better workaround is `datetime2(3)` as described in that link.

Comment: @DanGuzman When I click to add new column I saw only datetime2(7) and datetime2 in the dropdown. does this (7) means precision? Do you know about that? I dont see datetime2(3) in my MSSQL server Management Studio

Comment: @gunescelil, I assume you mean the graphical SSMS table designer. Just change the precision to 3. Any value from 0 to 7 is a valid.